# How can i override a method in a jar which is being called indirectly through functional flow in my code

Tags: java, jar, xml-parsing, overriding, xml-rpc

I have the execute method which is from xmlrpc.jar and xmlrpcserver.class this execute method takes inputs and processes it to execute internal method in the same class , this execute internal method has parse(input) which parses the inputstream, but this parse method is declared in a different class file called xmlrpc.class , i need to add a decoding method before parsing the inputstream, as there are many streams coming from different classes ultimately i need to add decoding method here in the parse method of xmlrpc.class how can i do it ? can i override the method ? but the execute method is in my class which extends xmlrpcserver not xmlrpc , i am confused how can i do it

this is how it looks

```
 byte[] result = xmlrpcserver.**execute** (request.getInputStream(), user, password);
 response.setContentType ("text/xml");
```

this is from another file

```
 server.**execute**("admin.deployStrategy", fixParams(params));
```

even though both execute methods are pointing to different class files in jar ultimately they are getting parsed by the parse method